# Replace entire array if value is greater than

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the below array with shape (2, 6, 3)

```
[[[ 10.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 20.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 60.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 40.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 20.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 80.          0.          0.        ]]

 [[ 70.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 90.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 20.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 50.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 80.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 10.          0.          0.        ]]]
```

I am trying to replace the complete array if the 1st value is >=50 with [1 1 1]
and if the first value is < 50 then the entire array should be with [0 0 0 ]

## Desired Output:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]]

 [[ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]]
```

I can replace only the single value but not the complete one.

Any idea on how can this be done

Comment: The shape is (2, 6, 3), no?

Comment: Can you show us the code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, sorry it's a typo error. I modified it :)

Comment: Could you (a) show what you've tried, and (b), show valid initialization code for the array that I can just copy into an interpreter?

Comment: In your input, it's the 3rd row from the top that exceeds 50 at the first cell - but in the Desired Output, it's the 4th from the top that is truthy. I'm not allowed to make edits that small myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach indexing from an array containing `[0,0,0]` and `[1,1,1]` based on the result of the comparisson:

```
b = np.array([[0,0,0], [1,1,1]])

b[(a[:,:,0] >= 50).view('i1')]

array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: I feel like you can use `np.choose` or so here.

Comment: `np.choose` sounds like a nice alternative here yes @mad

Comment: I was complicating my life here though, indexing with the original shape of course works fine too @mad

Comment: @yatu, Thanks for the answer. it would be much better if you just give me two lines of explanation for the Novice users. I am also trying to add one more condition in the code like b = np.array([[0,0,0], [1,1,1], [0, 1, 0]) for >30 and >60 and 60 to 100